# Add "Sort By" to custom product view

Tags: php, magento, sorting, toolbar

I'm trying to add the "Sort by" dropdown to my custom product view.
It worked with pager, but with sorter i get errors all the time.

This is what i try:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();


    $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');

    $toolbar = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar', 'custom.toolbar');
    $toolbar->setCollection($this->getCollection());
    $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);

    $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
    //  $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(10=>10));

    //$pager->setLimit(2);
    $pager->setDefaultOrder(array('popularity_by_sells'=>'popularity_by_sells'));

    $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
    $pager->setShowPerPage(false);
    $pager->setShowAmounts(false);
    $pager->setDefaultOrder('popularity_by_sells');
    $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
    $this->getCollection()->load();
    return $this;
}


public function getPagerHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}

public function getToolbarHtml(){
    return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
}
```

Here i get the fatal error:

> Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in [...]\src\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php on line 738

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the getLimit() function was a custom function, and simply added is_object()
in the if-clause.

```
public function getLimit(){
    $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
    if ($currentCategory !== false && is_object($currentCategory))
    {[...]}
}
```